# Use selenium to automate webpage that just works on Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pyvirtualdisplay

I’m trying to use selenium to automate a webpage that just works on IE, I cannot use Edge Compatibility Mode, once I’m using a Linux server (Edge for Linux doesn’t have the IE mode). Also I have tried Chrome plugins but it doesn’t work with selenium once it hides the html code. Any advice on this problem?

Also I’m using the xvfb wrapper for python in case that matters.

Comment: first advice: always show URL - so we could see this page and test it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the site uses special controls (eg ActiveX), it will only run in IE or Edge IE mode, modern browsers will not be compatible with it. And as mentioned, please provide code that reproduces the problem, it will help with the problem.

Comment: The url is in a internal network in my job, so that it’s not reproducible

Comment: If this is the case, I'm afraid we can't give better advice. And IE will stop support soon, I suggest you can pay more attention to modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to crawl a browser, you need to install its corresponding driver e.g, for google you install chromeDriver. For IE you install the ie driver.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/